# No <meta name="viewport"> tag found in the Next.js website

Tags: seo, viewport, next.js13

I've got a low SEO score on [Google PageSpeed Insight](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) for my site because of the following issue

```
No `<meta name="viewport">` tag found
```

I checked my page source and saw the tag with proper details as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

But somehow, the tag doesn't affect the page speed audits. I am using Next.js 13.5.4.

Could you tell me what I am missing?

I have no luck trying a [Next.js document methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-viewport) in the `layouts.tsx` file and new builts.

Comment: This identical question seems to have been asked recently. Anyway, Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.